# Prepared Statements And Stored Procedures

Tags: mysql, qt, stored-procedures, prepared-statement

I currentrly have to face [this](http://www.archivum.info/qt-interest@trolltech.com/2008-12/00296/%28Qt-interest%29-Problem-with-QSqlQuery-prepare-with-a-stored-procedure-%28MySql%29.html) problem. Since the post is nearly 4 years old, is there a solution for this now?

Short summary:

In Qt, you can prepare and execute a statement for MySQL which calls a stored procedure with some placeholders, but you cannot fetch the result in any way. Additionally you can only execute such a statement once, the second time you will get a "Commands out of sync"  error witch indicates that there is a result, but has not been fetched yet, in my understanding.

Comment: Please add a small self-contained *single file* (main.cpp only) example that opens an empty database, creates a stored procedure, and then calls it. Otherwise we'll be just doing your homework for you.

Comment: base on your link why dont use a variable inside qt?

Comment: What are the connector? do you have sample code?